How to remove bias/distribute more randomly the result of linear programming
I'm trying to make a program that allocate students into their preferred dormitories, the students rank the dorms from most to least favorite. I then use this data to model an Assignment Problem-type problem to input into an LP solver. It worked fine until I implemented a "Roomate preference", in which students can choose to be "coupled" with one and only one another and I will treat them as one entry that takes up twice the space. The solvers find an optimal solution nevertheless but always seems to push to couples to the generally least favorite residence by everyone, which is unfair. Here is my pseudocode:
N is number of students (
M is number of dorms
a[i] is 1 if entry i is not coupled, 2 if entry i is coupled (meaning 2 students are staying together)
c[i][j] indicates student i's ranking of dorm j, 0 is least favorite and M - 1 is most favorite
x[i][j] is a boolean: true if the students gets into dorm j, false if not

Objective: Maximize Sum of c[i][j] * x[i][j] for i: 0 to N - 1 and for j: 0: to M - 1

Constraints: 

Each student can only be allocated to one dorm: x[i][0] + x[i][1] + ... + x[i][M - 1] = 1

Each dorm can hold students only to its capacity: a[0] * x[0][j] + a[1] * x[1][j] + ... + a[N-1] * x[N - 1][j] = capacity of dorm j


I ran the program originally with glpk.js, and then used its .lp output to run it on SCIP, HIGHS,... on https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html, all seems to prefer putting the entry i with a[i] == 2 to dorm number 2, the least popular one, i tried to randomize the entry order, but nothing seems to change
Is there a specific setting that I can turn off for these solvers to make the solution less discriminative towards the coupled students, if only I can see them being allocated to other dorms?
I am a student myself and very new to LP and the solvers, so I would really appreciate if someone can give me guidance.
Thanks.

There's no code here; this is not reproducible.

The solver only discriminates using the objective value (and there are no guarantees to tie-breaking). You will need a formal model of improving fairness which you then need to model into the same LP. This is usually not that easy as there are often complex multi-objectives arising, e.g. lexicographic-ordered objectives. | Remark: I did not analyze your problem or model... but very often LINEAR models (or l1-norm) are problematic as 5 times deviate of 2 is the same as 1 time deviate by 10. In many (fairness) models, one prefers quadratic objectives (or l2-norm) which prefers the former.
